# How to display different texts depending on the browser language?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, switch-statement, getelementbyid

```
let language = navigator.language;

switch (language) {
    case es :
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hola ";
        break;
    case en :
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hello ";          
}
```

Am not receiving anything back.
I would appreciate if someone knows why it isn't working

Comment: Here's [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language) for reference. My browser returns "en-GB", for example, so you might not be picking up the right code. Note: in your code you also aren't putting those strings in quotes: that would be `'es'` or `'en'`.

Comment: Thanks @Andy for answering, I appreciate it, I also tried 
 ' switch (language) {
                case "es" :
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hola ";
                break;
                case "en" :
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hello ";
                
                }' 
 It is not working neither :(. I will check the documentation now

Comment: Open up the console.log of your browser dev tools and just type in `navigator.language` to see what it returns.

Comment: you were right @Andy, it doesn't recognise only 'en', I had to use 'en-GB' instead because that was the one my browser was showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wrap quotes around the possible values and you need to parse the `language` value to look like the values in your switch case:

```js
let language = navigator.language;
let dashIndex = language.indexOf('-');
if (dashIndex >= 0) {
    language = language.substring(0, dashIndex);
}

switch (language) {
                case 'es' :
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hola ";
                break;
                case 'en' :
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hello ";
                
                }
```

```html
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Note that instead of `case 'en' :` you could use `default :` which would use the English language as a default even if the language has a value that your code did not expect.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!, but I noticed that my browser's language is 'en-GB' and that the statement don't recognize it as 'en' , can the code recognise all the English variations?

Comment: @al3j4ndr0 this is why the example above is looking for dashes and if it finds, it sets language to the substring before the dash. It should work as it is for 'en-GB` as well. Please tell me whether the result found that to be en as expected during your tests. If so, then you might consider accepting this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <h1 id="demo">Hello World</h1>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

and my js file:

```
const language = navigator.language;
switch (language) {
                case 'es' :
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hola ";
                break;
                case 'en' :
                document.getElementById("demo").innerText =  "Hello ";
                
                }
```

You need to add quotes around you language switch case **'es'** not **es** ... Because [navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language) returns a string and if you don't use quotes javascript is going to be looking for a variable or a function call.

when I made those modifications your code worked just fine.